# How to stop anonymous session when using JWT and stateless sessions with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, jwt

I am currently using Spring Boot (Security) with JWT on a web app I have been creating. When the user logs in, the auth works fine - and they are redirected to the internal page with a JWT token that is set in a cookie on the front end in the browser. The session is instantiated with a `STATELESS` policy.

Subsequent requests will be signed with this token.

When the user sends another request, the app responses with 401 unauthorized, and it appears that it is due to an anonymous user session that has been set.

Here is my `WebSecurityConfig`:

```java
        http
            .headers()
                .xssProtection()
                    .and()
                .contentSecurityPolicy("script-src 'self'")
                    .and()
                .frameOptions().deny()
                .and()                               
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/pub/v1/**").permitAll()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/api/pub/v1/**").permitAll()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/pub/v1/**").permitAll()                
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and() //.httpBasic().and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http
            .csrf().disable();
        
        http
            .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

Changing the policy to `IF_REQUIRED` makes it work - but this results in Spring handling the session instead of JWT - resulting in irregular behavior.

How do I get the session to be recognized **not** as an anonymous user but the actual user context that gets set by the JWT handler upon login? It is as though this data gets lost, resulting in the user getting booted with any subsequent request.

// my JwtRequestFilter.java

```
       if (email != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            Users user = rootService.core().users().getByEmail(email).get();
            
            List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
            
            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, user)) {
                
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, grantedAuthorities);
                
                usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(
                        new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
                
                if (jwtTokenUtil.isLeadTimePassed(jwtToken)) {
                    String newToken = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(user);
                    response.addHeader("Set-Authorization", newToken);
                }
            }
        }
        
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

The setAuthentication does occur but it is like it is lost by the time it gets anywhere else.

Comment: So your `jwtRequestFilter` has a bug, you are not authenticated.

Comment: @dur the jwtRequestFilter sets the authentication successfully, it just appears to lose the authentication saved in spring?